# How to get Column names from dynamic result of ExecuteQuery

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is there any way to get Column names from dynamic result of `ExecuteQuery`, in linq-to-sql, following is the code snippet I tried, but it gives

> {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[0]} as return. Since my sql query is
>   extracted from database I can't map it with a predefined table

```
string sql = 'SELECT CustomX, CustomY FROM CustomTable';
var tabledata = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)dbLinq.ExecuteQuery<dynamic>(sql);

BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance |
                        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

PropertyInfo[] columns = tabledata.First().GetType().GetProperties(flags);
```

any help or alternate suggestions would be appreciated...
(I am using .net framework 4.0, SQL Server 2008)

**Edit :**
If this option does not work with dynamic result, can any one guide me to loop thru the first record and get the column names... Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever check the result of `ExecuteQuery<dynamic>`? It only returns featureless `object`s.

Comment: @Gert, yes its returning proper result, but not able to get attributes

Comment: No it's *not* returning proper results is what I'm saying. Yes you'll get rows, but they only contain objects of type `object`, nothing more. No attributes (properties) at all.

Comment: @Gert, thanks, I was not aware of that, can you suggest any alternate way to get column names at least by looping thru the records, I could not find any examples of such cases

Comment: hey man , did you find the way to read column names with executequery ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Name` property on the `PropertyInfo` object to get this.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < columns.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(columns[i].Name); // <-- will output in a name of a certain property
}
```

Comment: Bejger, thanks for quick reply, but Length is showing as 0, but I checked the tabledata, its having 190 records.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < columns.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(columns[i].Name); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Shahrooz, thanks for your reply, count needs to be used as count() else it gives error, but this also leads to 0